# MySQL binlog not logging

Tags: mysql, replication

Have added the directive in my.cnf

```
log-bin
```

Both the binlog and index files are created, but seems the binlog file remain unchanged even I massively insert data into the db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be a wild guess, but it sounds like this is either a secondary master or slave host? Add the following line to your my.cnf and restart mysqld:

```
log-slave-updates
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility might be that if you are inserting into a transactional table but have not committed the data yet with a `COMMIT` statement all those inserts would be cached.